# Legacy CD-ROM driver or program as a pass-through to a real CD/DVD drive

Tags: c#, api, cd-rom

I have a legacy program that reads/rips CD/Music data from a disk. It is a custom program that reads the track data and converts it to wma/wpa/wav format. The user then enters how it is to be licensed and the program ingests the data and music files to our LAN.

The issue is the program only works with a handful of CD-ROM drives. I was wondering if there was a program or some way to make the program point to a generic drive via driver or virtual drive and actually have it read a more advanced CD/DVD drive?

Here is a rough diagram.
[generic cd-rom virtual drive] ->[mapped to]-> [any number, make, or modal or cd/dvd drive]

This way my program will always see the same generic CD-ROM drive and I can install it on any PC with any type of CD/DVD drive.

Is this possible without having to perform a re-write on the program? I am really looking for a quick fix.

The program is written in C# Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite your program then you're probably in the wrong place, as Stackoverflow is for programming problems. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Does exist. It's called vmware.

Comment: It could be a quick fix programming ... fix. I just did not want to perform a "ground up" rewrite of the entire program. I am toying with the Virtual PC XP Mode from MS. I am not 100% sure if it will work or my company will go for it but I thought I would try an "easy for IT guys and end users" approach first.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing I ended up using XP Mode for Windows 7. This gave me a quick generic CD-ROM bolted to any CD/DVD drive. I know this is not technically a programming fix but it is a fix, in some way, to my issue. It will at least buy me some time until I can get and actual code fix in place. I will post the final fix if/when I find one.